# Twilio Worker Status Default

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

Is it possible to set a users status to Available by default?

As in when a worker currently logs in they are currently offline

[image: offline on twilio login]

Or currently if they miss a call they are set to offline by Twilio.
I would like them to be classed as online by default unless they set themselves to offline. Is that possible?

there are defaults in Flex Task Assignment. But they do not seem to control the worker being available upon login

[image: Flex settings]

And worker settings can be deleted but Offline seems to be a setting that should exist just one that I want only to be chosen.

Answer (score 2):

I think Flex puts an agent in the Offline activity to ensure that they only come available when they are ready.

You might be able to override this with a [Flex plugin](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins) that uses the [Actions framework](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/actions) to invoke the [`SetActivity` action](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.28.1/Actions.html#.SetActivity) with the SID of the activity you want them to be in.